# Convert Degrees of Latitude to Feet

Tags: arithmetic, spherical-geometry

I need to check this formula I have to compute the distance of a point with latitude $lat$ from the equator:

$$
\mathrm{feet} = \mathrm{lat} * 10000 \times 3280  / 90 
$$

Example: A point at $40.480125^\circ N$ has distance

```
40.480125 * (10000 / 90) * 3280 = 14752756.66666667 ft
```

from the Equator. My stored value for this is 1417623.

The problem I am having is the numbers are not making sense. I am told I have data that was already converted and is a 7 digit number, but all my calculations end up being an 8 digit number with a decimal.

Why doesn't the result make sense ?

Comment: Oh, so it's degrees of latitude. Your formula says a point on the earth @ 40.48 degrees of latitude is 14752756 ft away from the equator. This is roughly 4500 km. And makes (approximate) sense.

Comment: Yes, and the same for Longitude. I am not able to get a hold of the people who made the initial values/conversions to store in the database - imagine that! So I am guessing at what the conversion is really. UTM?

Comment: please review my edit and see if it makes sense.

Comment: Ok, do you see the difference I am getting and what do we attribute from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is taking the circumference of the Earth (assumed to be a perfect sphere) as *exactly* 40,000 km., which is OK to two significant figures.  The arclength along the Earth's surface is then found as

$$ \frac{\text{angle from Equator}}{90º} \ \cdot \ 40,000 \ \text{km.} \ \ , $$

and the result is converted to feet using $ \ \frac{3280  \ \text{ft.}}{1 \ \text{km.}} \ $ , alright to three significant figures.  The result is good to two significant figures.  Your result for 40.48º North *should* have eight digits, so someone else slipped up...

Comment: Well that's what I was wondering. Is it possible they were using a different function? Even if it had 8 digits it is off by 600,000.

Comment: The best explanation I can think of at present is: 1) all values in feet (since you said this is a database) have been divided by 10; and 2) someone used an incorrect conversion unit.  I tried assuming their number is a factor of 10 off and that they used an oblate spheroid for the Earth, instead of a sphere, but that doesn't give their first three significant figures correctly.

Comment: I have ArcGIS and when I select the `Feet` I got a 7 digit number - now I am very confused as to this equation being right - your thoughts?

Comment: I'd never heard of ArcGIS, so I went to their site, but unfortunately nothing is accessible without joining it.  I have also worked out your problem on a number of other sites that compute distances between points on the Earth's surface; all agree (nearly enough) with the distance in feet that you found.  The formula is _correct_.  The issue now is whether what you are getting from ArcGIS is actually solving the problem you want.  What are the inputs and how are the results presented?

Comment: The results are from clicking on a point on the map in order to get a lat/long. I can set the output several ways; decimal degrees, miles, yards, feet, etc...

Comment: `ArcGIS` is part of the `ESRI` company. I have a hard time believing they are wrong - this is my delima.

Comment: How are you asking it to give you the distance of a point from the Equator?  (I am thinking that what you _think_ you're trying to get from the map is not what the software is telling you.  Since I can't see any of this, I doubt I can trouble-shoot this...)